# How can I get rid of AttributeError problem?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, attributeerror, eoferror

When I upload the python file to codePost.io , I get an error that says "EOF Error when reading a line". I tried to use "try and except" method but in this case I get an AttributeError. What should I do? Here is my code:

```
try:
    rows = int(input("Enter a number of rows: "))
    columns = int(input("Enter a number of columns: "))

    def print_rect(row, col):
      for r in range(1, row + 1):
        for i in range(1, col + 1):
          if r == 1 or r == row or i == 1 or i == col:
            print("*", end="")
          else:
            print(" ", end="")

        print()

    print_rect(rows, columns)
except EOFError:
    pass
```

Comment: The code is fine. I guess `input` doesn't work on codepost.io.

Comment: How can I solve this problem then? Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: You should try to use something other than the codepost.io website to run your code. For example, you could install Python on your computer and run it locally.

Comment: My code runs perfectly on Pycharm etc. But this is an assignment that I have to upload to codepost.io :D I don't know what to do.

Comment: Then  you should talk to the person who is making you do that.

Answer (score -1):

Try this please:

```
try:
  print("Enter a number of rows:")
  rows = int(input())
  print("Enter a number of columns:")
  columns = int(input())

  def print_rect(row, col):
    for r in range(1, row + 1):
      for i in range(1, col + 1):
        if r == 1 or r == row or i == 1 or i == col:
          print("*", end="")
        else:
          print(" ", end="")

      print()

  print_rect(rows, columns)
 except EOFError:
    pass
```

Comment: @Nisa Aslan,  The problem occurs for custom input in some online judge. So it will not create any issue  If you submit this. It will not raise that error.

Comment: It didn't work, it still gives the AttributeError. Thank you so much for your answer btw. It gives the following error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File [codePost Test] Test 1: line 16, in <module>
    assignment0.print_rect(5,12)
AttributeError: module 'assignment0' has no attribute 'print_rect'

Comment: @NisaAslan, Can you submit it again please. There was an issue i fixed it!

Comment: It didn't work again :( It gives the same error that I shared.

Comment: @NisaAslan, Please use the last update of the code.

Comment: This time it gives the error that says "print_rect is not defined" :D I guess we should not recall the function at the end of the code.

Comment: @NisaAslan, Check the code as a  last attempt please.

Comment: The downvote is because nothing relevant is happening here. The original code doesn't have a problem, it's just being tried in an environment where `input` doesn't work. I don't recognize the web site, but if it's an online judge, then presumably it's expecting the program to get input in a different way (for example, from command-line arguments read by `sys.argv`. I downvoted the answer because the question should not be answered; it should be closed.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, Look her code was 100% ok. I didn't say there is an error on her code. But she was getting difficulties to submit it. Because some online judge  raise issues for taking input due to their env. So rather avoid this issue, we should face it to resolve it. The suggestion has been given for get rid of that input issue. And its a common problem for some online judge.   https://discuss.codechef.com/t/taking-input-python/10808/10    Problem issue raised in here: https://codepost.io/